# Tailwind media queries in ReactJS

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I have a div which contains a img inside a div. I'm trying to apply media queries which is in tailwind css.

```
<div className="flex">
    <img src="/assets/logo.png" className="h-20 md:w-2" alt="logo"/>
</div>
```

This `md:w-2` applies for the desktop. But not in mobile devices(Chrome-iPhone12 Pro). In mobile devices default width(h-20) is applying. This should be the other way around. In my tailwind CSS there are no any screen overrides. I tried by taking out  tag and tested any other places also. But it's still same. How may I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`h-20` applies `height`, not `width`. Did you mean to apply the `w-20` class instead?

As per [the documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/responsive-design#working-mobile-first):

> By default, Tailwind uses a mobile-first breakpoint system, similar to what you might be used to in other frameworks like Bootstrap.
>
> What this means is that unprefixed utilities (like `uppercase`) take effect on all screen sizes, while prefixed utilities (like `md:uppercase`) only take effect at the specified breakpoint *and above*.

So for your situation, you'd do:

```html
<img src="/assets/logo.png" className="md:h-20 w-2" alt="logo"/>
```

So that `w-2` applies for mobile devices and then `h-20` (or `w-20`) from `md:h-20` (or `md:w-20`) applies for desktop (viewports that meet the `@media (min-width: 768px)` media query from the default `md` breakpoint configuration).